# select max id of each id

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, max

I have two tables: tbComment and tbCommentStatus:

```
**tbComment**
CommentID     IsLocked
1             0      
2             0
3             1
4             0
5             1

**tbCommentStatus**
CommentStatusID  CommentID   StatusTypeID
105              1           1                
106              1           4                
107              2           1                
108              3           1               
109              3           4
110              4           1 
112              5           1
112              5           4
```

I want to return CommentIDs of a dataset of the highest CommentStatusIDs for each CommentID Where StatusTypeID = 4 and IsLocked = 1.

Basically, here I would return CommentIDs: 3,5 because their highest CommentStatusID has a StatusTypeID=4 and tbComment.IsLocked=1

Man, I hope this makes sense. If it doesn't I can clarify.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query.

```
SELECT c.CommentID, MAX(cs.CommentStatusID) MaxCommentStatusID  
FROM   tbComment c
       JOIN tbCommentStatus cs ON c.CommentID = cs.CommentID
WHERE  c.IsLocked = 1
AND    cs.StatusTypeID = 4
GROUP BY c.CommentID
```